# How to use action attribute of form tag in html?

Tags: python, html, forms

I am having trouble to put the right attribute in a `action` on `<form>` in HTML

I plan to create a DELETE button which on clicking would prompt a alert box for confirmation.

Upon receiving the right input  would delete that entry.

URL for deleting the file is given by "deleteFile?ID=$file_name"

Here is what I have developed so far:

```
<form METHOD="LINK" action="deleteFile?ID=$fileID"
    <input TYPE="submit" VALUE="Delete">
</form>
</td>
```

Can you please help for prompting for the alert box. I have written the code in JavaScript called `COnfirmDelete()`

I am not able to put all the pieces together like :

1. User would click on the button Delete
2. It prompts for a confirm the action
3. Delete the particular file
4. Return to home screen.

Comment: `ACTION=action=` should be `action=`. For a confirmation, add: `onsubmit="return COnfirmDelete()"`.

Comment: Do you already have the code to delete the file? What language is the code written in?

Comment: @RobW you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Rob, Sorry I corrected it now

Comment: Also, `METHOD="LINK"` is nonsense. Replace `LINK` with `POST` or `GET`.

Comment: The value of fileID  is not populated. The output is : `deletefile?` But the output should be deletefile?ID=m12.txt

Answer (score 1):

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/Xv2V4/2/
*It is better not to have script in html `script` tags, but JSfiddle won't recognize my functions defined below.*

**JS**

```
function ConfirmDelete() {

    /* if you need to check this ID or sth. else. */
    var fileId = document.getElementById("fileId"); 

    var user_confirm = confirm('Really delete this file?');

    /* Check your file ID or whatever you want to check here. */
    return user_confirm;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" action="deleteFile" onsubmit="return ConfirmDelete();">
    <!-- print $fileID with python to have it in HTML -->
    <input type="hidden" id="fileId" name="ID" value="$fileID" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Vow, Thanks a lot, I think this is precisely what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know python, but depending on it's integration you can probably either set the `location` via Javascript or toggle the `header` information to return to your home screen.